# Does a CPI method to a program leave any special footprint on the blockchain?

Tags: solana-program, program, cpi

Firstly, do I understand correctly that CPI call is *one* of the ways to call a method of program?

If so, only by examining a TX on the blockchain, will it be possible to distinguish a CPI call to a program from a *normal* one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CPI is when a program calls another program during a transaction.

You can see CPI as inner instructions in the solana explorer:

Here an example:
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/625sih8CkKT4pknX4JXuZSpH7awjfhDYcFpCDQDuwSTRxc9dD6JH5emk8Fi4TVQmWaeWiHS7xhD22s72LDHoaeQL

You can see its using the Jupiter Accounts Route and then does a CPI to flux beam.
[image]

Comment: `You can see its using the Jupiter Accounts Route and then does a CPI to flux beam.` -- I see a list of accounts and TXs. Where precisely is that observed?

Comment: By the way, when a browser wallet makes a swap, is CPI getting used too?

Comment: Yes every transaction can do a CPI into another program. You can see it marked as Inner Instruction in the solana explorer. Other explorers may show it differently

Comment: I'm not asking what a TX **can** do. I asked -- when a browser wallet makes a swap, is CPI getting used too?  **Or not?**

Comment: In other words: do browser addons or wallets, for swap operations, use CPI a) always b) often c) almost never?

Comment: Yes CPIs are also done when you use a browser wallet. And CPIs are used often.

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch a transaction with the `getTransaction` endpoint, you'll get all of the top-level instructions in the transaction in `transaction.message.instructions`, which are *not* CPIs. You'll also get the `meta.innerInstructions`, which are all of the CPIs.

More information at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction